# Prove the median and the altitude drawn to the hypotenuse make an angle congruent to the difference of the acute angles of a right triangle.

Tags: geometry

How would I go about proving this:

> In a right triangle, the median and the altitude drawn to the hypotenuse make an angle congruent to the difference of the acute angles of the triangle.

One solution is to construct each angle with a compass, subtract them, and then prove congruence through superimposing one on the other - but I'm sure there must be a more theoretical approach.

Comment: There is a circle that goes through the three vertices of the triangle, and its centre is the midpoint of the hypotenuse.  That gives you some isosceles triangles that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let  $BC$ be the hypotenuse, $AH$ the altitude corresponding to $BC$ and $AM$ the median that corresponds to $BC$.

Due to a theorem, we have that $AM=\dfrac{BC}2=BM=MC$. Thus, we have 2 isosceles triangles $\triangle ABM, \triangle AMC$.

So, we have that $$\angle ABM=\angle BAM=x \text{ and  } \angle MAC =\angle ACM=y.$$

Moreover, $\angle HMA=2y$ as exterior angle of $\triangle AMC$.

Working in the right triangle $\triangle HMA$, we have that the blue angle is: $$\angle HAM=90^\circ-2y\, (1)$$

However, $$x+y=90^\circ\, (2)$$

From (1), (2) we have that the blue angle is: $$\angle HAM =90^\circ-2y=x+y-2y=x-y.$$

**Note**: Without loss of generality, we considered $\hat B > \hat C$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ABC$ be the a right triangle, $\angle ACB = \pi/2$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$, and $H$ the feet of the altitude through $C$, and suppose WLOG that $\angle CAB \geq \angle CBA$.

Note that the circumcircle of the triangle has center $M$, which means $\angle CAB = \angle ACM$. Meanwhile, since the altitude is orthogonal to the hipotenuse, you can deduce that $\angle CBA = \angle ACH$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof below is simpler and perhaps easier to follow than the other proofs. Afterwards, I answer how *you* could find it.

### Solution

Consider $\triangle ABC$ with right angle $\angle A$, median $AM$, and altitude $AH$.  We must show that $\angle HAM = |\angle B - \angle C|$.

Assume WLOG that $\angle B \geq \angle C$ and that $H$ is between $B$ and $M$.  Since $\angle HAM = \angle MAB - \angle HAB$, it suffices to prove that $\angle MAB \cong \angle B$ and $\angle HAB \cong \angle $C.

Observe that since $\triangle HAB$ is a right triangle, then $\angle HAB$ is complementary to $\angle B$ and therefore congruent to $\angle C$.

Now recall that the [median of a right triangle equals half its hypotenuse](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Median_to_Hypotenuse_of_Right_Triangle_equals_Half_Hypotenuse), so $AM \cong BM \cong CM$.  Therefore, $\triangle MAB$ is isoceles, and $\angle MAB \cong \angle B$.  This completes the proof.

---

### How you might have found it?

Proofs like this do not pop into anyone's head from thin air.  One way you could have found it is: Note the **key difficulty** of the problem is: The claims $\angle HAM = \angle B - \angle C$ concerns a subtraction.  How do we *subtract* angles geometrically?

The only obvious way is via **whole-part** relationships: Note that $\angle HAM$ is *part* of $\angle MAB$, so that $\angle HAM = \angle MAB - \angle HAB$.  This *suggests* that there might be a simple and direct correspondence: $$\angle MAB : \angle B \\ \angle HAB : \angle C.$$  If we can show this, we're done.

Now, we haven't used the entire hypothesis yet: Our result can't be true for *any* triangle and *any* lines, but only with $AH$ being an altitude, $AM$ a median, and $\angle A$ right.  Let's plug those in and see if they give us the correspondence.

The first is easy: Since $\angle AHB$ is right, then both $\angle C$ and $\angle HAB$ complement $\angle B$.  So we have half of our correspondence! This gives confidence we're on the right track.

Now for the other half.  It's not as obvious.  So we'll use another trick: Assume our desired result is true.  Ask what that would imply.  And see if we can reverse the steps (i.e. using the inverse).

If we assume that $\angle MAB \cong B$, then we have an isosceles triangle $\triangle MAB$.  This implies that $AM \cong BM$ - and that implication is invertible! So if we can show $AM \cong BM$, we're done.

How do we do that? Amateurs start over from scratch.  Pros **use theorems**.  Do we have any theorems that relate $AM$, a median, to $BM$, half the corresponding side?  We do for a right triangle, which is what we're dealing with.  Put this all together and we are done.